# Used Access 2007 query wizard to create SQL, still will not run in VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, wizard

I'm trying to write VBA in access 2007 that goes through one table and grabs all the records with the appropriate testcode and adds them to a table specifically for only that tescode. The first sql string is supposed to go through the code-specific table to find the latest date that was entered. The second sql string is supposed to find the one entered at the latest time on that date. And the third is supposed to take that date and time and grab all the records from the general table for that testcode that were entered since the last update and move them to the code-specific table.

I actually used the query wizard to generate the first two sql statements, yet i keep getting the error:

A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement.

The only thing I changed after I copied and pasted the SQL statement was that I added the proper quotation marks and stuff, so I am not sure why it won't work. It also means I can't check the later code, since I can't get through the first part.

My question is, how can it be wrong if I copied and pasted it from the wizard? Below is the section of my code. I was using the messageboxes to read through and \check the SQL statements for problems.

```
dateSQL = "SELECT Max(tbl505.TESTDATE) AS MaxDATE " & _
    "FROM tbl505 " & _
    "HAVING (([tbl505].[Plant]='Freeport'));"

MsgBox (dateSQL)
DoCmd.RunSQL dateSQL

timeSQL = "SELECT Max(tbl505.TESTTIME) AS MaxTIME " & _
    "FROM tbl505 " & _
    "HAVING (([tbl505].[Plant]='Freeport')) AND (([tbl505].[TESTDATE]= #" & MaxDATE & "#;"

MsgBox (timeSQL)
DoCmd.RunSQL timeSQL


 strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl505 (ORDERNO,CODE,BATCHNO,TESTNO,TESTDATE,PRODDATE,TESTTIME) " & _
    "SELECT ORDERNO,CODE,BATCHNO,TESTNO,TESTDATE,PRODDATE,TESTTIME " & _
    "FROM DSResultFRP " & _
    "WHERE DSResultFRP.[TESTDATE] >= #" & MaxDATE & "# AND DSResultFRP.[TESTDATE] > #" & MaxTIME & "# AND DSResultFRP.[TESTCODE] = '505'"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Comment: You are better off with CurrentDb.Execute or better yet, an instance of CurrentDb and add in dbFailOnError. Use the immediate window (ctrl+g) and debug.print to see your SQL. What is the point of the first two queries, you do not seem to do anything with them?

Comment: I'm trying to use the first two just to set up the max date and max time variables that I use in the third one to sort through the records. There might be a better way to do this, but I am pretty new to using SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DoCmd.RunSQL is only for action-type queries (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).  In the context you are using it for your first two queries, it doesn't make sense to the command.  If you want to use the values returned in those queries, look into a DAO/ADO recordset solution, or a DMax function solution.

Comment: Thank you, the DMax function is a WAY easier way to do what I wanted to do and I was able to replace both of the first two SQL statements. With those in, the code ran perfectly.

Comment: @user3827021: Cool, glad that worked for you.  If you get the time, please mark the solution posts as answers so if someone has the same question in the future, they know what a working solution is.  Take care.